# File upload with Codeigniter to Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, codeigniter-3

I have a web project running with codeigniter on google vm. In the admin panel of this project, the user must be able to upload a file with the help of the form given. But as far as I understand, we cannot use codeigniter's upload feature via google vm. For this, I think we need to create a bucket in google cloud storage and connect it to each other. The website is running smoothly on google vm, except for the upload feature, and the codes written work with the upload function on localhost or another server. If anyone has done this kind of procedure before or has a solution suggestion about the issue, I would be glad if they help me.

To summarize, what I want to do is; Uploading files to the bucket I created on google cloud storage with codeigniter running on google vm.

Comment: How big are the files?

Comment: What is the error when it fails? Does the VM has the same OS and configuration on the localhost where it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is entirely due to me. I noticed that I was unable to upload the file due to my server configuration errors. The thing that confuses me is that when I had a problem, I saw many people who had such upload problems in my research on the internet and I thought that uploading files would only be possible with google cloud storage. If someone has such a problem in the future and thinks that they cannot upload files with php on google vm instance, it is definitely possible! :) Thank you John and Alex!